# Rsyslog unable to send multiline logs

Tags: regex, parsing, apache-kafka, fluentd, rsyslog

I'm unable to push the below logs via rsyslog. The rsyslog is only forwarding one line of the log.

Kafka-server logs:

```
[2022-07-25 11:43:45,091] INFO KafkaConfig values:
    advertised.host.name = null
    advertised.listeners = INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092,BROKER://0.0.0.0:9091,CLIENT://0.0.0.0:9093
    advertised.port = null
    alter.config.policy.class.name = null
    alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.num = 11
    alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
    authorizer.class.name =
    auto.create.topics.enable = true
    auto.leader.rebalance.enable = true
    background.threads = 10
    broker.id = 0
    broker.id.generation.enable = true
    broker.rack = null
    client.quota.callback.class = null
    compression.type = producer
    connection.failed.authentication.delay.ms = 100
    connections.max.idle.ms = 600000
    connections.max.reauth.ms = 0
    control.plane.listener.name = null
    controlled.shutdown.enable = true
    controlled.shutdown.max.retries = 3
    controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms = 5000
    controller.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
    create.topic.policy.class.name = null
    default.replication.factor = 1
    delegation.token.expiry.check.interval.ms = 3600000
    delegation.token.expiry.time.ms = 86400000
    delegation.token.master.key = null
    delegation.token.max.lifetime.ms = 604800000
    delete.records.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1
    delete.topic.enable = true
    fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
    group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms = 3000
    group.max.session.timeout.ms = 1800000
    group.max.size = 2147483647
    group.min.session.timeout.ms = 6000
    host.name =
    inter.broker.listener.name = BROKER
    inter.broker.protocol.version = 2.3-IV1
    kafka.metrics.polling.interval.secs = 10
    kafka.metrics.reporters = []
    leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds = 300
    leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage = 10
    listener.security.protocol.map = INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,BROKER:PLAINTEXT,CLIENT:PLAINTEXT
    listeners = INTERNAL://:9092,BROKER://:9091,CLIENT://:9093
    log.cleaner.backoff.ms = 15000
    log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size = 134217728
    log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms = 86400000
    log.cleaner.enable = true
    log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor = 0.9
    log.cleaner.io.buffer.size = 524288
    log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second = 1.7976931348623157E308
    log.cleaner.max.compaction.lag.ms = 9223372036854775807
    log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio = 0.5
    log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms = 0
    log.cleaner.threads = 1
    log.cleanup.policy = [delete]
    log.dir = /tmp/kafka-logs
    log.dirs = /var/lib/kafka
    log.flush.interval.messages = 9223372036854775807
    log.flush.interval.ms = null
    log.flush.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
    log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms = 9223372036854775807
    log.flush.start.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
    log.index.interval.bytes = 4096
    log.index.size.max.bytes = 10485760
    log.message.downconversion.enable = true
    log.message.format.version = 2.3-IV1
    log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms = 9223372036854775807
    log.message.timestamp.type = CreateTime
    log.preallocate = false
    log.retention.bytes = -1
    log.retention.check.interval.ms = 300000
    log.retention.hours = 120
    log.retention.minutes = null
    log.retention.ms = null
    log.roll.hours = 168
    log.roll.jitter.hours = 0
    log.roll.jitter.ms = null
    log.roll.ms = null
    log.segment.bytes = 1073741824
    log.segment.delete.delay.ms = 60000
    max.connections = 2147483647
    max.connections.per.ip = 2147483647
    max.connections.per.ip.overrides =
    max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots = 1000
    message.max.bytes = 1000012
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    min.insync.replicas = 1
    num.io.threads = 8
    num.network.threads = 3
    num.partitions = 1
    num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir = 1
    num.replica.alter.log.dirs.threads = null
    num.replica.fetchers = 1
    offset.metadata.max.bytes = 4096
    offsets.commit.required.acks = -1
    offsets.commit.timeout.ms = 5000
    offsets.load.buffer.size = 5242880
    offsets.retention.check.interval.ms = 600000
    offsets.retention.minutes = 10080
    offsets.topic.compression.codec = 0
    offsets.topic.num.partitions = 50
    offsets.topic.replication.factor = 1
    offsets.topic.segment.bytes = 104857600
    password.encoder.cipher.algorithm = AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
    password.encoder.iterations = 4096
    password.encoder.key.length = 128
    password.encoder.keyfactory.algorithm = null
    password.encoder.old.secret = null
    password.encoder.secret = null
    port = 9092
    principal.builder.class = null
    producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
    queued.max.request.bytes = -1
    queued.max.requests = 500
    quota.consumer.default = 9223372036854775807
    quota.producer.default = 9223372036854775807
    quota.window.num = 11
    quota.window.size.seconds = 1
    replica.fetch.backoff.ms = 1000
    replica.fetch.max.bytes = 1048576
    replica.fetch.min.bytes = 1
    replica.fetch.response.max.bytes = 10485760
    replica.fetch.wait.max.ms = 500
    replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms = 5000
    replica.lag.time.max.ms = 10000
    replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    replica.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
    replication.quota.window.num = 11
    replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    reserved.broker.max.id = 1000
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.enabled.mechanisms = [GSSAPI]
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.principal.to.local.rules = [DEFAULT]
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol = GSSAPI
    sasl.server.callback.handler.class = null
    security.inter.broker.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 102400
    socket.request.max.bytes = 104857600
    socket.send.buffer.bytes = 102400
    ssl.cipher.suites = []
    ssl.client.auth = none
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.principal.mapping.rules = [DEFAULT]
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.abort.timed.out.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 60000
    transaction.max.timeout.ms = 900000
    transaction.remove.expired.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 3600000
    transaction.state.log.load.buffer.size = 5242880
    transaction.state.log.min.isr = 2
    transaction.state.log.num.partitions = 50
    transaction.state.log.replication.factor = 3
    transaction.state.log.segment.bytes = 104857600
    transactional.id.expiration.ms = 604800000
    unclean.leader.election.enable = false
    zookeeper.connect = 0.0.0.0:2181
    zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms = 18000
    zookeeper.max.in.flight.requests = 10
    zookeeper.session.timeout.ms = 6000
    zookeeper.set.acl = false
    zookeeper.sync.time.ms = 2000
 (kafka.server.KafkaConfig)
[2022-07-25 11:43:45,145] ERROR Fatal error during SupportedServerStartable startup. Prepare to shutdown (io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedKafka)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: advertised.listeners cannot use the nonroutable meta-address 0.0.0.0. Use a routable IP address.
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.validateValues(KafkaConfig.scala:1492)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1460)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:1114)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.fromProps(KafkaConfig.scala:1094)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.fromProps(KafkaConfig.scala:1091)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.fromProps(KafkaConfig.scala)
    at io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedServerStartable.<init>(SupportedServerStartable.java:52)
    at io.confluent.support.metrics.SupportedKafka.main(SupportedKafka.java:45)
```

rsysconf.d/10kafka.conf

---

```
$InputFilePollInterval 1
input(type="imfile"
  File="/var/log/kafka/server.log"
  Tag="app-error"
  Severity="error"
  startmsg.regex="^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}"
)

*.* @Fluentdvmip:5142
```

Can someone please guide how to send complete logs from rsys to Fluentd?
Below is the regex which I'll be using in fluentD configuration.

https://regex101.com/r/NaNVcr/1

or do we need to modify kafka log4j properties to have proper logging?

Comment: `^[[:digit:]]{4}` doesn't match `[2022`. You are missing an open bracket `\[`. You should also fix your Kafka configs, according to the error output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sending Kafka server logs into RSYS. First, I converted Kakfa logs into Json format.
Created a Jar using this [Link](https://github.com/thmshmm/log4j-json-layout)

Steps Followed

1. Git clone the above link in VM where kafka was installed
2. Installed maven latest version
3. Ran `mvn package` inside the recently cloned directory
4. A jar was created inside target directory "log4j-json-layout-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
5. Copied this jar to /usr/share/java/kafka/
6. Added the below code in /etc/kafka/log4j.properties and commented the older code

   log4j.appender.kafkaAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
   log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/server.log
   log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout=de.thmshmm.log4j.JsonLayout
   log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout.DatePattern=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
7. restarted confluent-kafka service

Before logs:

[image]

After Logs:

[image]